# how to solve The "srsearch" parameter must be set error in wikipedia api

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const search = async () => {
      await axios.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php", {
        params: {
          action: "query",
          list: "search",
          origin: "*",
          format: "json",
          srsearch: input,
        },
      });
    };
    search();
  }, [input]);
```

the error is :

> {code: "missingparam", info: "The "srsearch" parameter must be
> set.",…}

Answer (score 0):

```
    srsearch:{input}
```

i did this mistake of putting input without {}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).